# How to Draw 100's to 1000's of basic shapes without freezing the display in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tried using a simple for loop:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPFGamesChess
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(makeGrid);
        }

        public void makeGrid()
        {
            Size s = new Size(20, 20);
            for (int y = 0; y < s.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < s.Width; x++)
                {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    if ((x+y) % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        r.Fill = Brushes.Black;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        r.Fill = Brushes.White;
                    }
                    r.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    r.StrokeThickness = 0;

                    double h = (RootGrid.Height / s.Height);
                    double w = (RootGrid.Width / s.Width); 

                    r.Height = h;
                    r.Width = w;

                    r.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, RootGrid.Width - r.Width - (x*w*2), RootGrid.Height - r.Height - (y*h*2));
                    RootGrid.Children.Add(r);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, doing it this way prevents the display from loading as far as I can tell. I figured that this would need to be multi-threaded, but I can't figure out how to do that either. What I'm trying to do is make a grid for a chess board, but I'd like to be able to re-use that code for making a larger grid for a strategy game.

Comment: Multithreading will not help here. Drawing can only be done on one thread (UI thread). You have to think about a different approach for presenting so many shapes. Maybe consider drawing it to bitmap and manipulate individual pixels. You can also use high performance libraries for drawing 2d shapes. Or don't use wpf for writing games.

Comment: would I use the writeable bitmap to be able to do that/how would that be any faster?

Comment: Writable Bitmap is basically just a RGBA buffer. This is probably the fastest way you can draw something. But Writable Bitmap operates on individual pixels, so I would recommend using specialized libraries for drawing 2d shapes instead.

Comment: If it's just a black and white grid, the fastest way to draw it would be DrawingBrush with [TileMode.Tile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.tilebrush.tilemode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Do you just want a checkerboard or will other shapes in a less regular pattern be involved? Hexes or irregular shapes like some gaming systems use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827561/how-to-create-checker-board-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need a few thousand objects...and most of them won't animate...then regular data-binding should handle that fine without tying up the GUI thread. Here's an example from [an application I wrote](https://github.com/Myndale/Perfy) in which each grid cell contains 17 different elements, that's almost 15,000 in total:

[image]

This is implemented with an ItemsControl using a Canvas as the panel and DataTemplating to select the types of elements to create. I don't notice any discernible pause at start-up, and real-time editing etc is perfectly smooth.

Also, since you specifically mentioned chess, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563181/1177147) of that I created earlier using the same technique, with the following result:

[image]